# I want to read the content of a text file which contain file names and check if they are availale the folder or not

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, cgi

I am new to Linux and I am making a program to save me some time. So basically the program should read the content of a text file containing the files names as an XXX-XXX.mp3 format and it should chek if there is a missing file or additional files that are not in the text file.

```
path="/user/desktop/test1/"
cd ${path}

echo "Filecheck:"
for i in $(cat test1/text/test??.txt|cut -c 1-7|grep -R '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]'|sort|uniq)
do
[ -f test1/$i.mp3 ] || echo "$i.mp3 passed."
done
```

this is what I reached for and it display the titles inside the text file but I am not sure now how to continue to check the file in the folder

Answer (score 0):

A bit ugly, but this will give you an idea where to move on:

```
#!/bin/bash

path="/user/desktop/test1/"
cd ${path}

echo "Filecheck:"

ls *.mp3 > tmp_list.txt

diff test1/text/test??.txt tmp_list.txt | grep '<\|>' | sed -e 's/</File not found:/g' | sed -e 's/>/File not listed:/g' | sort
```

Comment: thank you @the.Legend for your answer, You gave an idea of how to start working i tested your code but it did now display anything so i used 
   //    path="/user/desktop/test1/"   //   cd ${path}   //      ls *.mp3 > tmp_list.txt 
     //      grep -v -f tmp_list.txt text/test??.txt      //           Now it compares the files and display what is diffrent with respect to the text file but does not indicate what is available in the tmp_list.txt but not available in the test??.txt files. Do you have any idea how to fix this issue?